# TestNG not executing all tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse, testng-annotation-test

I have created the following method to execute the methods given a list of .class:

```
  public static <T> void executeTestNew(String testName, List<Class<?>> test) {
    try {
        List<XmlClass> parsedTests = test.stream().map(XmlClass::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        XmlSuite xmlSuite = new XmlSuite();
        xmlSuite.setGroupByInstances(true);
        xmlSuite.setName(testName);
        XmlTest xmlTest = new XmlTest(xmlSuite);
        xmlTest.setName(testName);
        xmlTest.setClasses(parsedTests);
        testng.setXmlSuites(Collections.singletonList(xmlSuite));
        testng.setVerbose(2);
        testng.run();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.printf("There was a problem executing %s \n", testName);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        System.out.printf("%s finished \n", testName);
    }
}
```

From main method I pass them some tests:

```
 executeTestNew("Test", Arrays.asList(
            Test1.class,
            Test2.class,
            Test3.class,
            Test4.class,
            Test5.class,
            Test6.class,
            Test7.class,
            Test8.class,
            Test9.class));
```

The problem is that only 5 tests are executed at once, if you try to execute more than 5 in one session, they will be skipped.

EDIT:

I've checked that if the Asserts (Test NG asserts) fails in any of the tests, the remaining tests are not executed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I've just taken your method and it executed all 7/7 test classes I've passed to that method. Try to leave only skipped classes in your list and retry. I think the issue is somewhere out of the code you're demonstrating..

Comment: I've cheked that if the asserts inside the tests fail, the remaining tests are not executed

Comment: Just added explicit `Assert.fail()` to one of my tests. Still showing all tests executed but 1 failed. No skipped.

Comment: @NexussimLements are you using the latest version of testng?